# Why is $x = 90$ not a possible solution to $3\cos(x) = \sin(x + 30)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am working through a past paper and this question came up:$$3\cos(x) = \sin(x + 30)$$

I got the answers that were given in the past paper ($x = 70.9, 251$) as well as two others: $x = 90, 270$

This is from:
$$5\cos(x) - \sqrt{3}\sin(x) = 0$$
$$\cos(x)[5 - \sqrt{3}\tan(x)] = 0$$
resulting in:
$$tanx = \frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}, \cos(x) = 0$$

I know from trying $\cos(x) = 0$ solutions into the original equation that this isn't a correct answer but I can't work out why.

Comment: $\tan\frac{\pi}{2}$ is not defined

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki its in degrees however what do you mean?

Comment: $\tan\,x=\frac{sin\,x}{\cos\,x}$ and we should have $\cos\,x\ne\,0$

Comment: @Cjen1 the tangent value of any angle $\theta$ with $\cos \theta=0$ is not defined, no matter which units you use. More obviously, you should check your answers in the original formula.

Comment: @Joffan thanks for your answer, however please look at the last line of my questions

Comment: What you've done is pretty much the same as writing $S+C=0\implies C(\frac{S}{C}+1)=0$ and from this concluding $C=0$ or $S/C=-1$. But if $C=0$, then this would mean $S+0 = 0(\frac{S}{0}+1)$ which isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, what you should have done  is add a statement between the two derivation lines 
$$5\cos(x) - \sqrt{3}\sin(x) = 0$$
**>>> then, for $\cos x \ne 0$ <<<**
$$\cos(x)[5 - \sqrt{3}\tan(x)] = 0$$

- because you're dividing the terms by $\cos x$ to extract it as a factor, which is only valid if $\cos x \ne 0$

Comment: Does the same logic hold true for something like: $x(x+1)=0$ ?

Comment: If you try to manipulate the formula to say $1\cdot\dfrac{x+1}{x} = 0$, and claim that $1=0$ is a possible result, then yes. :-)